# Firebase Crashltytics: crash ID

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

Fabric Crashlytics have shown unique ID for each crash, so was easy to track in version control. Does Firebase Crashlytics show ID anywhere? I can't seem to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only visible in the URL, after `issues/` (double click works to select it).

One still could [Link Firebase to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765) and query the data, eg. by issue ID:

> Details from Crashlytics fatal and non-fatal crash events and stack traces

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Bunch of hex numbers aren't really user friendly though :/